# Need help optimizing function call

Tags: c, performance, optimization, function-pointers, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to implement an image processing function. Here it is:

```
typedef void (*AgFilter)(int*, int*, int*, float*);

static void filter(AndroidBitmapInfo* info, void* pixels, AgFilter func, void* params){

    for(y = 0; y < height; y++){
        for(x = 0; x < width; x++){
            //initizalie r, g, b

            func(&r, &g, &b, params); //here is the problem
        }
    }
}
```

I'm passing this function as `func`:

```
static inline void brightness(int *r, int *g, int *b, float* param){
    float add = param[0];

    *r += add;
    *g += add;
    *b += add;
}
```

Problem that it's works extremly slow. Well, I can understand that. **But** if instead of passing function by reference I write my function directly inside the `filter` (instread of `func` calling) it's works much much faster. Where is the problem?

P.S. note that it's not `c++`

**EDIT**

This one works fast:

```
static void filter(AndroidBitmapInfo* info, void* pixels, int add){

    for(y = 0; y < height; y++){
        for(x = 0; x < width; x++){
            //initizalie r, g, b
            r += add;
            g += add;
            b += add;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that shows the performance difference? Otherwise, we can only guess at it.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't inline the call ?

Comment: @cnicutar Yeah, that's what I'm thinking too. Compilers generally suck at inlining function pointers.

Comment: What's "slow" and what's "fast" here? It would be faster if you don't pass it as a parameter because then it can't be inlined (leading to more cache misses), but unless you need to do this a bajillion times per second this shouldn't be very noticable. " Compilers generally suck at inlining function pointers." Well how would you inline a pointer?

Comment: @Cubic If you look at the nature of the code, it's pretty clear that the OP is indeed doing this a bajillion times per second.

Comment: In any case, even without running any benchmarks. I think the answer is pretty obvious. There are a LOT of optimizations that can be done if the function is inlined. But the compiler probably isn't able to inline the function pointer.

Comment: I've simplified the code and provided "fast" example. Thanks for response.

Comment: I'll get some disassemblies together and make an answer if you're interested.

Comment: @Cubic unfortunately I can't provide precise numbers. But "as I feel it": slow - 0.5 time per second, fast - 30 times per second.

Comment: @Mysticial it would be great :)

Comment: How exactly can you expect the compiler inline this at all? Also, do you *always* call this function with the *same* function argument? Even so, I wouldn't expect a compiler to verify that all calls use the same function as argument, and then inline it.

Comment: @Mysticial I would imagine it's quite difficult but I don't know much about compilers.

Comment: The only practical way this will get inlined using the function pointer is if (a) the call to `filter` is inlined into its caller, and then (b) data flow analysis shows the optimizer that the value of `func` must be the address of `brightness` (because that's what the caller passed to `filter`). Then the compiler/linker could inline `brightness` into the caller of `filter`. So see whether you can arrange for both those things to happen, with an eye on the disassembly to tell whether it worked or not.

Comment: @cnicutar It falls along the same lines as compile-time devirtualization - but harder. If the compiler can't prove definitively that `brightness` is the only possible function pointer that will be used, then it cannot inline the function. There are some (but very limited) tricks around this, but they are very niche and I doubt any compilers actually implement them.

Comment: I don't think I can get any reasonable disassembly since the code isn't anywhere near SSCCE. But the answer is inlining. And there are a lot of optimizations that can be done if the function is inlined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling functions takes time. Usually, you don't notice but you call that function a million times (about two million times for a full HD 1920x1080 image). Modern cameras create 16 Megapixel images. If each call takes 1 us, the accumulated time for calling the function (without actually executing the body) will be 16 *seconds*.

How can you make it faster? Some suggestions:

1. Instead of passing four parameters, use a struct:

   ```
    struct data { int r,g,b; float* param; }
   ```

   allocate this once and reuse it. Now you can call `func` with a single argument.
2. Memory layout might be a problem. `param` is anywhere in memory. Copy it into `struct data` instead:

   ```
    struct data { int r,g,b, add; }
   ```

   The reason for this is that `param` is anywhere in memory which means it's probably in a different cache line. If you can fit all the data into a single 64 byte structure, all will fit into a single cache line which can give a huge performance boost.

   But probably not in your case since you always access `param[0]`. This is more an issue when you would access the array in a random way.
3. Swap shift and bit mask operations:

   ```
    r = (int) ((line[x] & >> 16 ) & 0xFF);
   ```

   Can give a small boost since all three colors will now be masked with `0xFF` and that allows the compiler to move the constant once to a CPU register.
4. When calling functions, all the CPU registers need to be "saved/restored". That costs time. When the function is inlined, the compiler knows which CPU registers is trashed and can optimize accordingly.

   Actually, the CPU registers aren't saved (at least I haven't seen that for a long time). Modern compilers just assumes that after calling the function, all of them have been changed.
5. Note that `inline` has no effect since you pass the function by reference instead of directly calling it.
6. Use threads. This is dead simple to parallelize: Run the function N times (one per CPU core) on 1/N-th of the data. That will give you roughly a N time performance boost.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the problem is because you are passing your function as pointer. Because of that *brightness()* is not inlined by the compiler.

When you copy definition of *brightness()* into the *filter()* function, you get your desired result - you inline the function.

Answer (score 1):

By far the biggest improvement you can make is to avoid calling the function once for each pixel. It is trivial to move your loop inside the `brightness` function.

```
static inline void brightness(int *r, int *g, int *b, float* param){
    float add = param[0];

    for(y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for(x = 0; x < width; x++){
            //initialize r, g, b
            *r += add;
            *g += add;
            *b += add;
        }
}
```

Now, I know you don't want to have to duplicate the loop-iteration code inside every different filter function you might write, so this is one of the cases where using macros can really make a difference. Try something like this (untested).

```
#define FOR_EACH_PIXEL for(y = 0; y < height; y++) \
                       for(x = 0; x < width;  x++)

static inline void brightness(int *r, int *g, int *b, float* param){
    float add = param[0];

    FOR_EACH_PIXEL 
    {
            //initialize r, g, b
            *r += add;
            *g += add;
            *b += add;
    }

}
```